# Sql Union or Join or both together

Tags: mysql, sql, join, union

I have 2 tables `AmountIn` and `AmountOut`.

The first table `Amountin` looks like :

```
AmountIn
+--------+--------------+-----------+
| account| date         | AmountIn  |
+--------+--------------+-----------+
| A      |  2017/2/6    | 200       |
| A      |  2017/2/5    | 100       |
| A      |  2017/2/5    | 500       |
| B      |  2017/2/1    | 1000      |
| B      |  2017/2/1    | 2000      |
| C      |  2017/1/20   | 25        |
+--------+----+---------+-----------+
```

And the second one looks like:

```
  AmountOut
+--------+--------------+-----------+
| account| date         |AmountOut  |
+--------+--------------+-----------+
| A      |  2017/2/8    | 200       |
| A      |  2017/2/7    | 100       |
| A      |  2017/2/6    | 500       |
| B      |  2017/2/2    | 1000      |
| B      |  2017/2/1    | 2000      |
| C      |  2017/1/20   | 25        |
+--------+----+---------+-----------+
```

Now I want a query that will display result as follow:

```
ForAccountA
+--------+--------------+----------+-----------+------------+
| account| date         | AmountIn | AmountOut | Balancy    |
+--------+--------------+-------- -+-----------+------------+
| A      |  2017/2/5    | 500      | 0         | 500        |
| A      |  2017/2/5    | 100      | 0         | 600        |
| A      |  2017/2/6    |   0      | 500       | 100        |
| A      |  2017/2/6    | 200      | 0         | 300        |
| A      |  2017/2/7    | 0        | 100       | 200        |
| A      |  2017/2/8    | 0        | 200       | 0          |
+--------+----+---------+----------+-----------+------------+
```

`date field` in the query is an union of date in both tables and the balancy is calculated as :

```
last balance + AmountIn - AmounOut
```

Comment: You need a `JOIN`. `UNION` not going to work here

Comment: thank you for your fast reply , but how to JOIN and keep Date field as one getting dates from both tables

Comment: Looks like a FULL OUTER JOIN. But I don't think MySQL supports it.

Comment: FULL OUTER not directly supported but can be done using  select joining query union all select inverted joining query where inverted_left.joining_column is null

Comment: how  the query would look like?

Comment: It looks like homework, isn't it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select
    t.*,
    @sum := if(@account = account, 
                @sum + AmountIn - AmountOut,
                if((@account := account) is not null,
                    AmountIn - AmountOut, 0)
            ) balance
from (
    select
        *
    from (
        select
            1 x,
            account,
            date,
            AmountIn,
            0 AmountOut
        from AmountIn
        union all
        select
            0 x,
            account,
            date,
            0 AmountIn,
            AmountOut
        from AmountOut
    ) t order by account, date, x
) t cross join (select @account := null, @sum := 0) t2
```

#### EDIT:

For three tables:

```
select
    t.*,
    @sum := if(@account = account, 
                @sum + amountOne + amountTwo - amountThree,
                if((@account := account) is not null,
                    amountOne + amountTwo - amountThree, 0)
            ) balance
from (
    select
        *
    from (
        select 
            2 x, account, date, amount amountOne, 
            0 amountTwo, 0 amountThree
        from table1
        union all
        select
            1 x, account, date, 0 amountOne,
            amount amountTwo, 0 amountThree
        from table2
        union all
        select
            0 x, account, date, 0 amountOne,
            0 amountTwo, amount amountThree
        from table3
    ) t order by account, date, x
) t cross join (select @account := null, @sum := 0) t2
```

Comment: Hi, This seems  to be very helpful but  what if the fields 'AmountIn'  and 'AmountOut'  have the same name:  'Amount' in the tables

Comment: Doesn't matter. Use whatever column name you have and put an alias after it. `amount as amountIn` or `amount as amountOut`

Comment: As I said, it wouldn't matter. You can use column aliases.

Comment: Thanks a lot @GurV you are perfect, and of tables are 3 with same structure where balance is tableone amount + tabletwo amount - tablethree amount. Please how the code would look like ? Thanks again

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much @GurV

Comment: Hello thank you again I want to know if it can be ordered by Date descending, to show the last operations on top, I tried
  
        'from table3
    ) t order by account, date desc, x
) t cross join (select (AT)account := null, (AT)sum := 0) t2' but the balance gets mess

Answer (score -1):

```
Select
       case when a.account is not null 
            then a.account else b.account
       end as Account, 
       case when a.account is not null then a.date
            else b.date as date, 
       a.AmountIn, b.AmountIn, (a.AmountIn - b.AmountOut) as balance
       from AmountIn 
a  left join ForAccontA on a.account = b.account where a.account = 'A' and 
b.account = 'A'
```

Hi I would like to solve this query like this rather redundant code using union

Answer (score -1):

MSSQL:

```
select ai.account,
       ai.date,ai.AmountIn, 
           case when AmountIn is NULL then 0 
           else 0 
       end as AmontOut  
from AmountIn as ai
where ai.account = 'A'
union
select ao.account,
       ao.date,
       case 
           when AmountOut is NULL then 0 
           else 0 
       end as AmountOut, 
      ao.AmountOut 
from AmountOut as ao
where ao.account = 'A'
```

this returns your desired table without column balancy. Maybe someone help you out with this column